# Java code to post on FB business page wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Does anyone has an idea how can I post text/images on facebook BUSINESS page wall from my webserver (Java).

I know how to do it on personal profile (involving Apps) but for business page I ahve no idea, since I have found out that cannot create an App for FB business page.

Answer (score 0):

You do it with an app as well, but you get a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) first.

Comment: But how can I ceate application for business page?

Comment: Just like any other app – apps on Facebook are not tied to any specific type of profile or page. https://developers.facebook.com/apps